# /bin/sh: Odd string comparison error 'unexpected operator'

Tags: shell, sh

Found this error to be quite weird because previously my script was working and but after I moved it from the server I was working on to my local machine, it stopped working and just gave me an 'unexpected operator' error.

```
# Else if the script is being run in the arrayscripts directory, add /output/ ...
elif [ $basePath == "arrayscripts" ];
then
        echo "$dscr has started to run."
        cpuPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.binary"
        txtPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.txt"
        csvPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.csv"
```

Comment: You are likely running this using a POSIX shell, probably `dash` (default `sh` in Ubuntu) which doesn't support `==`.  See [Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)

Comment: If this shell is bash, the obvious problem is missing quotes. `"$basePath"` is not the same as `$basePath` -- unquoted, the latter can expand to any number of arguments, making what it puts in the operator position completely unpredictable.

Comment: Since you tag this `bash`, are you starting your script with `#!/bin/bash`? If not, you should.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy starting it with #!/bin/sh thought it was bash, sorry for tagging the wrong thing

Comment: FYI, using `\`pwd\`` is considerably less efficient than `$PWD`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your actual shell is `/bin/sh` [contrary to the initial question, but as discussion commentary has made clear], use `=` rather than `==` in your test expression:

```
elif [ "$basePath" = arrayscripts ]
```

Note that the right-hand side *doesn't* need to be quoted in this case, since it contains no expansions and no syntactically-sensitive characters.

---

Alternately, if this issue is reproducible when using bash, the obvious problem is missing quotes.

Use either

```
[ "$basePath" = arrayscripts ] # this is POSIX compatible
```

or

```
[[ $basePath = arrayscripts ]] # this works only with bash
```

Otherwise, the number of arguments `$basePath` expands into is undefined -- it may expand into zero arguments, making the statement

```
[ = arrayscripts ]
```

...which would try to use `=` as a unary operator, which it isn't...

or if `$basePath` contained, say, `"true -o bar ="`, it could expand into something like

```
[ true -o bar = arrayscripts ]
```

...resulting in program behavior very different from what you actually want.

---

Bottom line: When writing for shells which follow POSIX rules (basically, anything but zsh or fish), quote your expansions unless you have a specific and compelling reason to do otherwise. (Use of the bash/ksh extension `[[ ]]` provides such a reason, by introducing a context in which string-splitting of expansion results and glob expansion don't take place).

Comment: For completeness, I thought I'd mention that quoting won't prevent [ = arrayscripts ] situations. What seems to be recommended is using [ ".$basePath" = .arrayscripts ] so that if basePath is undefined you're left with [ . = .arrayscripts ].

Comment: @bobpaul, that claim is incorrect: `[ "" = arrayscripts ]` -- which `[ "$emptyvar" = arrayscripts ]` evaluates to -- is not a syntax error; in any POSIX-compliant shell, it correctly compares an empty string on the left to a non-empty string on the right.

Comment: @bobpaul, ...you can test this yourself: Run `[ "$emptyvar" = arrayscripts ]`, and note the lack of any syntax error reported to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

This is an error you'd get if you were executing the script with a POSIX shell like `dash`.  `dash` is the default `/bin/sh` on some platforms such as Ubuntu and Debian.

`==` is specific to `bash` ( [Bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) ) and is not compatible with POSIX shells like `dash`, which uses only `=` to test string equality.

In the context of single brackets, `==` and `=` are treated as the same operator in `bash`, so either can be used.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, updated the tags so I included Ubuntu which was the operating system I was using

Comment: @MOS182, more important to stop tagging it `bash` when your shell is actually `sh`.

Comment: Note that although `bash` supports `==` inside `[ ... ]`, there's no reason to actually do so. Use `[[ ... == ... ]]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my script working by changing the comparison function from '==' to '=' as suggested by 'alister' in the unix and linux forums ( http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/141856-how-avoid-unexpected-operator-error-when-comparing-2-strings.html ) and so my script looked like this

```
# Else if the script is being run in the arrayscripts directory, add /output/ ...
    elif [ "$basePath" = "arrayscripts" ];
    then
            echo "$dscr has started to run."
            cpuPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.binary"
            txtPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.txt"
            csvPath="`pwd`/output/cpu.csv"
```

Hope that if anyone gets this same error as I did, that this answer will help them.
.

Comment: You posted question and answer together at same time. And since you tagged as `BASH` your answer is also wrong.

Comment: Bash treats `= and ==` the same.  From `man bash`: `The = operator is equivalent to ==`.

Comment: @anubhava why is my answer wrong?

Comment: @JohnB: Already answered your question in his comment.

Comment: @anubhava John has said that = and == are treated the same, in that case how is my answer wrong? Why was I getting an error when it was == and not = ?

Comment: When `==` itself is not causing any problem how will your answer be justified for BASH?

Comment: @MOS182, `==` works fine for bash. The comment given was relevant for /bin/sh, which bash is not.