# Shell Scripting Unexpected Operator

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have been struggling with this problem for hours and tried everything I could find on discussion boards. I cannot switch to `bash`, this is intended to be in `bin/sh`.

The problem is with the while loop, `while [ $currentID -gt 0 ]`. The error is `" 21: [: 2893: unexpected operator`

```
#!/bin/sh

Menu_Option=0

echo "WELCOME"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
while [ $Menu_Option -ne 4 ]
do
    echo "select a menu option"
    echo "1- ancestry history"
    echo "2- who is online"
    echo "3- what process any user is running"
    echo "4- exit"
    read Menu_Option
    case $Menu_Option in
  1)
        echo "THE ANCESTRY TREE FOR CURRENT PROCESS IS...."
        echo " "
        ps -ef > file1
        currentID=$(awk '{if ($3 == '$PPID') print $2}' file1)
        while [ $currentID -gt 0 ]
        do 
            Process_Name=$(awk '{if ($2 == $currentID) print $8 "  " $9}'     file1)
```

Comment: Have you checked what `currentID` is set to? Adding something like `echo $currentID` after you set it, to see what you're getting back from `awk`.

Comment: It is returning multiple values. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your intentions and what values are being returned?

Comment: I am intending to find the current process ID to map out the process tree. It is returning 4 process ID's

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that means 4 processes have the same `PPID`, the current process' `PID` should be in `$$` in `bash`, not sure about `sh` you'll have to verify.

Comment: Do not forget to *quote* your variables, especially in `[ ... ]`. You are just asking for trouble if you don't. (this can lead to your error, if you haven't figured that out...)

Comment: I'd recommend running your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/bin/sh: Odd string comparison error 'unexpected operator'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846454/bin-sh-odd-string-comparison-error-unexpected-operator)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following is what you need:

```
#!/bin/sh

Menu_Option=0

echo "WELCOME"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
while [ $Menu_Option -ne 4 ]
do
        echo "select a menu option"
        echo "1- ancestry history"
        echo "2- who is online"
        echo "3- what process any user is running"
        echo "4- exit"
        read -r Menu_Option
        case $Menu_Option in
        1)
                echo "THE ANCESTRY TREE FOR CURRENT PROCESS IS...."
                echo " "
                ps -ef > file1
                currentID=$(awk '{if ($3 == '$PPID') print $2}' file1)
                while [ "$currentID" -gt 0 ]
                do
                        Process_Name=$(awk '{if ($2 == '"$currentID"') print $8 "  " $9}'     file1)
                        echo "$Process_Name"
                        currentID=$(awk '{if ($3 == '"$currentID"') print $2}' file1)
                        if [ "$currentID" = "" ]
                        then
                                currentID=-1;
                        fi
                done
                echo ""
        esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you. I am curious as to why you used single quotes around double quotes in the awk statements.

Comment: Once I was done with the script, I got it reviewed with http://www.shellcheck.net and got the feedback. Made the changes accordingly.